# JPEG2000 API for Python

Tags: python, jpeg2000

I am about to run a simulation in which I need to encode and decode image files with JPEG2000.  I need an API that gives me flexibility to tune coding parameters and set output quality.  Is there any API for Python to do so?

Comment: This seems to be a paradigm library recommendation question. It _might_ be answerable on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but read their help first. But the best place is probably some kind of site more oriented toward subjective discussion than objective answers. The [Community](https://www.python.org/community/) section at python.org has a list of mailing lists and IRC channels; if none of the more specific ones seem appropriate, try `python-list` or Freenode `#python`.

Comment: Anyway, as far as I know, most of the popular libraries (Pillow, cv2, etc.) come with JPEG2000 support built on OpenJPEG, and there's a low-level wrapper named something like py-openjpeg that provides essentially the same API as OpenJPEG does in C, and probably a bunch of other options as well.